# Why the MySQL TIME method behaves different inside a SELECT vs UPDATE?

Tags: sql, mysql

When I ran the following query I didn't get an error:

`SELECT * FROM requested_schedules WHERE TIME('foo');`

On the other hand, if I ran the following query:

`UPDATE requested_schedules SET date_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE TIME('foo');`

I get the error `[22001][1292] Data truncation: Truncated incorrect time value: 'foo'`

MySQL Version is 8.0

If you want to test it:

```
CREATE TABLE requested_schedules(
    date_updated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

EDIT: Those are not queries that are supposed to return something relevant, are just to demonstrate the error. The original query from which I got the problem gets time as strings. Most of the time it will look something like this `TIME('13:00')`. But sometimes it can get an empty string such as `TIME('')` and when it does returns the error. It was a bad design and I already changed but the thing is I am curious why it returns an error when used in an UPDATE and not when used in a SELECT.

Comment: What is `time ('inactive')` supposed to do?

Comment: In this example demonstrates the error, it could be anything that is not a valid time. I added more info to the post sorry for not being more specific.

Comment: You need to read about MySQL modes. Whether the datetime functions throw warnings or errors, and whether errors are thrown in select or update... It's all covered there.

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be some misunderstanding in the way you are using the `TIME()` function. Here is a [reference to usage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

It accepts datetime as an argument and extracts time from the provided argument. `Inactive` does not represent date-time values, so that won't work.

Edit your question or provide more clear details on the result you are expecting or trying to achieve.

Also, does your SELECT query return anything?

**Edit**

This answer might not be relevant as the original question was changed completely after this answer was posted.

It might be due to the context in which these queries are executed. In a SELECT query with an invalid value, MySQL might be lenient and allow the query to proceed, possibly returning the default value or handling errors differently. Also, in the UPDATE query, there might be stricter validations, leading to errors being thrown when an invalid value is encountered.

Comment: OP's question is different now. They're asking why invalid value works in select but not in update.

Comment: Yes, the question has completely changed now.